# Array of dates In node.js - I have an error : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can you help me to make this code works with more than 100k entries.

```
  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates));
  var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates));
```

For now I have this error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please share some more code or what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a recursion problem here.
It seems the stack used in recursion has a maximum size that's why the Math.min and Math.max most likely crash for big arrays because they are both recursive operations.

Instead, you can use old javascript loops like so:

```
function getMax(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((max, v) => max >= v ? max : v, -Infinity);
}
```

Or

```
function getMax(arr) {
    let len = arr.length;
    let max = -Infinity;

    while (len--) {
        max = arr[len] > max ? arr[len] : max;
    }
    return max;
}
```

(The second is much faster)

Answer (score 0):

I think,your dates array is not correct;
you can check this code:

```js
var dates=[];
for(var i=0;i<100001;i++){
  dates.push(randomDate(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date()));
}

var max = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates));
var min = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates));

\\console.log(dates);
console.log('Max is:'+max);
console.log('Min is:'+min);

function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It works for small array. It's a recursion problem like Lamine said